# Variables not behaving when trying to access data

Tags: php

I want to set my class variables not in the __construct but in a method called by the __construct. I'm not sure if I'm going about this right.

```
class request{
private $sNote;
private $iAffectedUserId;
private $iUserId;
private $sPassword;
private $sFirstName;
private $sLastName;

public function __construct($sService, $oData, $iAffectedUserId){
    $this->iUserId = $_SESSION['user_Id'];
    $this->sPassword = $_SESSION['password'];
    $this->sFirstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];
    $this->sLastName = $_SESSION['lastName'];
    switch($sService){
        case 'note':
            $this->requestNote();
            break;
        default:
            echo "ErrorCode: 4000";
            break;
    }
}

public function requestNote(){
    $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM `note` WHERE `sender_Id` = '" . $this->iUserId . "'";
    echo $sQuery;
    $oResult = conn($sQuery);
    if(!is_array($oResult)||!isset($oResult)||empty($oResult)||is_null($oResult)){
        echo "ErrorCode: 5000";
    } else{
        //echo $this->iUserId;
        echo json_encode($oResult);
    }
}
}
```

The result from this code leaves my `$sQuery` with a blank value where `$this->iUserId` is. This means nothing is returned.

Other way code was written.

```
class request{
private $sNote;
private $iAffectedUserId;
private $iUserId;
private $sPassword;
private $sFirstName;
private $sLastName;

public function __construct($sService, $oData, $iAffectedUserId){
    $this->init_Session_Variables();
    switch($sService){
        case 'note':
            $this->requestNote();
            break;
        default:
            echo "ErrorCode: 4000";
            break;
    }
}

private function init_Session_Variables(){
    $this->iUserId = $_SESSION['user_Id'];
    $this->sPassword = $_SESSION['password'];
    $this->sFirstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];
    $this->sLastName = $_SESSION['lastName'];
}

public function requestNote(){
    $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM `note` WHERE `sender_Id` = '" . $this->$iUserId . "'";
    echo $sQuery;
    $oResult = conn($sQuery);
    if(!is_array($oResult)||!isset($oResult)||empty($oResult)||is_null($oResult)){
        echo "ErrorCode: 5000";
    } else{
        //echo $this->iUserId;
        echo json_encode($oResult);
    }
}
}
```

This way gives me an error saying:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: iUserId in **C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\MyVyn\Utils\utils\php\userQuery.php** on line **95**

I'm really at a loss here. What is blowing up?

Comment: What's not clear about the error message? Also, you couldn't narrow the code down any more than this?

Comment: are you sure _SESSION is set?

Comment: @JohnConde There are two different results for two different sets of code. The error is very clear, but that doesn't exactly tell how where I'm messing up. I tried setting the variable and accessing it how I know, so if you know of another way then please enlighten me. That is why I'm turned to stackoverflow and other people for help.

Comment: @Serg I believe the variables are set because other parts of the site that require them to be set are working fine.

Comment: @Serg I think I you were correct about the _SESSION. Even though the session is set for other parts of the site, on this page they are being wiped out.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra $ in front of iUserID

```
 $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM `note` WHERE `sender_Id` = '" . $this->$iUserId . "'";
```

should be

```
 $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM `note` WHERE `sender_Id` = '" . $this->iUserId . "'";
```

Comment: I tried that in the first set of code above. It return nothing, because the variable in the query string is empty for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure there's data in $_SESSION['user_Id'] ? Make sure that the session variable is spelled right, capitalization matters. If whatever code populates that hasn't run, then it will be empty. If that's a problem, your constructor should be checking that.